# How can I reference MVC item/model in HTMLAttributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to list two radio buttons in each row of a table, but I haven't been able to assign unique IDs to each radio button.  I'd like to assign the IDs based on the @item.myID as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton("Yes", @item.myID, @item.IsCool, new { id = "@item.myID", autopostback = "true" })
            @Html.RadioButton("No", @item.myID, !@item.IsCool, new { id = "@item.myID", autopostback = "true" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

However, the IDs keep rendering literally as "@item.myID".  In other words, it's not treating the @ sign as a special character.  I've also tried using parenthesis, like this: "@(item.myID)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes from around the id assignment, like so;

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton("Yes", item.myID, item.IsCool, new { id = item.myID, autopostback = "true" })
            @Html.RadioButton("No", item.myID, !item.IsCool, new { id = item.myID, autopostback = "true" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Also, note that you don't need the additional "@" symbol when you are already in the context of another Razor code block - the Razor View Engine is pretty clever :)

Comment: Also, it's recommended to keep ids unique, the radiobuttons will be grouped by the "name"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you don't need that "@" next to item.myID either.